# How can I get user's ip address without registration system for post view count with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, module

There is no registration system in my application. I'm thinking of creating a middleware and saving the user's ip address to mongodb. When the user requests a dynamic post, if the user's ip address is registered in mongodb, the number of views of the post will not increase. If the user's ip address is not registered in mongodb, the number of post views will increase by one. I need the user's ip address to be able to do all this. How can I learn it?

Answer (score 0):

Vsay
Try the Morgan package with

```
npm install morgan
```

after that require in your `app.js` or `server.js` mean in the root file

Then pass as a middleware you will get all Log Details in the File where you create with that middleware, If you didn't get let me know...

Hope it's work for you...